# git bash pull and clone commands fail

Tags: git, bash, github, clone, pull

The "clone" command from Git Bash does not do anything. 
Here is the context:
I have cloned my professor's repository.
And I am pulling changes from his master branch. 
His repo is INFO253-webarch... and the subfolders are: hw-1, ... to hw-7.

**When I pull from his master branch, nothing is updated on my computer.**

```
Audrey@Audrey-PC MINGW64 ~/Git/INFO253-webarch-1/hw-7 (hw-7-branch)
$ git pull kayashaolu master
```

For example he created hw-7 folder, which contains a file: but it does not show on my computer.
To help me troubleshoot, here is [git config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7EFK.png), here is [git status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjoWg.png).
And here is what `git remote -v` gives:

```
Audrey@Audrey-PC MINGW64 ~/Git/INFO253-webarch-1 (master)
$ git remote -v
kayashaolu      https://github.com/kayashaolu/INFO253-webarch (fetch)
kayashaolu      https://github.com/kayashaolu/INFO253-webarch (push)
origin  https://github.com/audreyCEE/INFO253-webarch-1.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/audreyCEE/INFO253-webarch-1.git (push)
```

If it helps, here is what `git branch -vv` gives:

```
    Audrey@Audrey-PC MINGW64 ~/Git/INFO253-webarch-1 (master)
$ git branch -vv
  hw-1-branch 5f8609f Removed file from the wrong folder
  hw-2-branch 4324070 Change made in the titles 09-10-2015 10 44 pm
  hw-3-branch 028d476 I had forgotten ; in a line
  hw-4-branch df699ce Other typo noticed
  hw-5-branch 8e0d2cb answers added
  hw-6-branch 4403df4 parameters ok
  hw-7-branch 7f17c07 This is a test to solve the issue.
* master      e2b2d8b [origin/master: ahead 25] Redirect location fix
```

I have also tried to create a new folder on my computer, and clone again, but the "clone" command does not do anything: the new folder remains empty. I don't receive any error messages, and not even an update message.

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT/ WHAT I IMPLEMENTED:**
**After many failed attempts to solve the problem, I ended up uninstalling and re-installing git!**

Comment: Don't use the four word version of git-pull it doesn't do anything particularly useful.

Comment: Your master branch is 25 commits ahead of origin. What does `git remote show kayashaolu` output? What does `git fetch -v --all` output?

Comment: `git remote show kayashaolu` does not return anything. 
and here is what I get for fetching: 
`$ git fetch -v --all
Fetching origin
error: Could not fetch origin
Fetching kayashaolu
error: Could not fetch kayashaolu`

Comment: Yeah, so that `kayashaolu` repository doesn't exist (at least not publically). Are you sure that's correct? You have a `hw-7-branch` branch locally is that where the change you are expecting to see should be?

Comment: What does this do: `git remote update` and `git checkout origin/master`?

Comment: It is a private repo. But it was working before. I had been added as contributor. The changes should be on his master branch. and I'd like to import all the changes on my hw-7-branch. Does it answer your question?

Comment: `Audrey@Audrey-PC MINGW64 ~/Git/INFO253-webarch-1 (master)`
`$ git remote update` 
Fetching origin
error: Could not fetch origin
Fetching kayashaolu
error: Could not fetch kayashaolu

Comment: ~~~
`Audrey@Audrey-PC MINGW64 ~/Git/INFO253-webarch-1 (master)`
`$ git checkout origin/master` ~~~~
Note: checking out 'origin/master'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

`HEAD is now at 352b286... Sample commit`

Comment: Config seems correct, it *should* work - also as it worked before and as `git clone` in a different place doesn't work, I would blame the current state of OS being funky, which leads me to suggest a very generic restart for starters. If no luck, try upgrading git? If you're using default installation on OS X, it will probably be outdated - get Homebrew and get latest version with `brew install git`.

Comment: It sounds like *both* remotes went away.  Since this is a bit unlikely, perhaps instead what went away was your access key.  (I'm not sure why you're using https with github, instead of ssh, but either way you'd need an access name-and-password.)